# Cant rig specific mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging

There's this cat that I'm trying to rig, and no matter what I do it wont work. I've tried fixing any mesh errors that I could find, but I can't find any more, it seems clean now.
I've remeshed it with instant meshes and the new mesh works rigs nicely. Hope you guys can identify what is my error in this mesh...
Link file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIb7WQPs5sT4KhtT8j4cRsVCkPTvlVMH/view

Comment: Your mesh is too dense, I don't know why, technically, it makes the parenting fail but I think it is your problem here, and anyway, using a high-poly mesh will make animation very tedious, so you should come back to a low-poly version of your cat. You probably applied a Subdivision Surface modifier, did you keep the low-poly version? If not you'll have to retopolgize your object.

Comment: Hey, some time later I come back... I've redesigned the cat and now have a low poly of it, the automatic weight is working fine, only thing is the rig is getting a weird parenting in the cheek now...
Heres the glitch: [glitch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJYw86fQ8GYLJNVcULKR7qJdcWCYGkUQ/view?usp=sharing)
And how the armature is laid out: [armature](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12QvQoWBd1E-H3FiAPJt9xLI7D1Wbj1cf/view?usp=sharing)
also a link to the blend file: [cat.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIb7WQPs5sT4KhtT8j4cRsVCkPTvlVMH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello, your link to the blend file asks for an authorization   ;)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the quick response, I've corrected it!

Comment: The blend file should have the armature in it... Sorry for the mess lol, was it hidden? idk

Comment: Try this one [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K1MNFauTawmDHvSFpbXz_9r6seraHxBu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: maybe you should precise what doesn't work according to you. It looks like you've auto-rigged, maybe you should 1) work with a low-poly mesh, it will make the things much easier for calculation or deformation 2) rig yourself, so that you can fully and easily control the influence of each bone?

Comment: got it, will work on that. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Fo rexample unless you have good reasons to keep it high poly, try to work with a low-poly version, I've used Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide and it looks like it doesn't make any difference, it will make it much easier imho

Comment: Oh, thats a nice one, I've applyed the subdivision before cuz the shrink wrap was kinda strange, that will sure do.

Comment: keep your mesh as low-poly as possible, also, keep a low-poly version even if you try to apply the Subdivision Surface, don't apply this modifier if you have no reason to. Also, I'm not familiar with auto-rig but I think you can make your own armature pretty easily.

Comment: I acctualy used rigify, saves a lot of time... I'll try to solve this with some weight painting, if it doesn't help I'll do my own.